# Loop in dict python

Tags: python, loops

I have already looked around but have not found any help for this.
This is my dict:

```
 {'id': 1, 'name': 'Studio Pierrot'}
 {'id': 29, 'name': 'VAP'}
 {'id': 102, 'name': 'FUNimation Entertainment'}
 {'id': 148, 'name': 'Hakusensha'}
 {'id': 238, 'name': 'AT-X'}
 {'id': 751, 'name': 'Marvelous AQL'}
 {'id': 1211, 'name': 'Tokyo MX'}

aproducers = an.info['Producers'][0]['name']

for key in aproducers:
    print key
```

The output is like:

```
 S
 t
 u
 d
 i
 o
 ...
```

I want to output just Studio Pierrot,VAP,FUNimation Entertainment...

Comment: When you say "this is my dict", I don't think it means what you think it means... you're iterating the string rather than the list of dicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re looping over a string, the single `name` value of the first producer. You need to loop over the producers instead:

```
for producer in an.info['Producers']:
    print producer['name']
```

Comment: thank you , is there any way to set the result to a variable ? listproducer = loop result

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the methods keys() values() items() and to use nested dicts

for the last question you can just use:

```
  listproducer = [] 

  for producer in an.info['Producers']:
      listproducer.append( producer['name'] )
```